# strategy pattern or builder pattern?

Tags: strategy-pattern, builder-pattern

I know the strategy pattern is a behavioral pattern that encapsulate an algorithm in a class. Also that the builder pattern is to separate the construction of a complex object.

Now, I have to create different views of map (seller view, customer view) (each map has: houses, buildings, streets) depending on a type that in be selected in the UI by the user. I want to do this as extensible as possible as maybe some other views will be added to the program. In this case, should I create a strategy which encapsulates the algorithm to create the different views? or should apply the builder pattern? or should I create a strategy with a builder inside?.

```
public class Map
{
  private List<House> Houses { get; set; }
  private List<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
  private List<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}
```

In the UI:

- Select with: Seller view, Customer view.
- Map: shows the map with all his things and depending on the select, depends the view that is shown.

Seller view: houses and building in green are for sale, and in red are sold.

Customer view: house in blue is the selected to buy and only appears houses in sale.

Thanks and wish you understand my problem!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have a different  *behaviour* depending on user role. Therefore it is suitable to have different *strategies* of presenting the data. Using the *builder* pattern inside of strategies sound reasonable as well when you have to construct a complex obiect.